# Postgres - select rows except where count is more than one and another condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, exists

I have a table with the following sample data:

```
appuser_id     business_id     role_id
6              2               CLIENT_MANAGER
8              2               CLIENT_ADMIN
6              3               BUSINESS_MANAGER
8              3               BUSINESS_MANAGER
6              4               BUSINESS_MANAGER
8              5               BUSINESS_MANAGER
8              6               BUSINESS_MANAGER
```

I'm looking to create a function that pulls a list of all businesses for a user where his role is `'BUSINESS_MANAGER'`, however, if multiple people manage a business (business 3 above), and one of the users happen to also have a `'CLIENT_ADMIN'` role on any other business, I want to skip that contended record (skip business 3 that is), basically, given this query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE appuser_id = 8 AND role_id = 'BUSINESS_MANAGER' AND ???;
```

I want the following results:

```
appuser_id     business_id     role_id
8              5               BUSINESS_MANAGER
8              6               BUSINESS_MANAGER
```

and for the same query for user 6 I want:

```
appuser_id     business_id     role_id
6              3               BUSINESS_MANAGER
6              4               BUSINESS_MANAGER
```

I have no idea where to begin something like this.

If anyone has a better title, please feel free to change.

Comment: `... and one of the users happen to also have a CLIENT_ADMIN role on any other business, I want to skip ` **<<--** You could use `... AND NOT EXISTS(...)`

Comment: BTW: It would help if you formulated your requirements in a more exact manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was suggested in the comment, you can use `not exists`:

```
select * 
from my_table mt
where mt.appuser_id = 6
and mt.role_id = 'BUSINESS_MANAGER' 
and mt.business_id not in (
  select imt.business_id
  from my_table imt
  where exists (
    select *
    from my_table iimt
    where imt.appuser_id <> iimt.appuser_id
    and iimt.appuser_id = mt.appuser_id
    and iimt.role_id = 'CLIENT_ADMIN' 
  )
)
```

Comment: Hi, this does not return any results no matter what I try for some reason.

Comment: @Mankind1023 thanks for the input, please try again, I've changed `imt.business_id` to `mt.business_id` in the inner select to fetch `appuser_id`s

Comment: still not working :S

Comment: @Mankind1023 please, try it now; I have created a db fiddle, so you can check it and write a query that does not return what you expect: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=133fb3ab987cf32f3c11f0a827a1d00e